# Как занести Юнита в базу данных

Tags: php

```
<?php
echo "<h1>Регистрация</h1>";
$submit = strip_tags($_POST['submit']);
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
$repeatpassword = strip_tags($_POST['repeatpassword']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$startpoke = $_POST['startpoke'];

if ($submit)
{
 // check for existans
if($name&&$password&&$repeatpassword&&$email)
{

if ($password==$repeatpassword)
{

//check name
if(strlen($name)>15||strlen($name)<4)
{
echo "Логин должен быть от 4 до 15 символов!";
}
else
{
 //check password
if (strlen($password)>25||strlen($password)<6)
{
echo "Пароль должен быть от 6 до 25 символов";
}
else
{

if (isset($_POST['name']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];
}

if (isset($_POST['password']))
{
$password = $_POST['password'];
}

if (isset($_POST['email']))
{
$email = $_POST['email'];
}

if (isset($_POST['date']))
{
$date = $_POST['date'];
}

if (isset($_POST['ip']))
{
$ip = $_POST['ip'];
}

 //encrypt password
$password =md5($password);
$repeatpassword =md5($repeatpassword);

//open database
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vladon12");
mysql_select_db("testgame");
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (name,password,email,date,ip) values('$name','$password','$email','$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (name_poke) values('$name_poke')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `inventar` () values()") or die(mysql_error());

die ("Добро пожаловать в игру =) Нажми <a href='index.php'>здесь</a> для продолжения
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color: #A6CAF0 ;
color: #330033 ;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 2%;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>");

}

}

}
else
echo "Пароли не совпадают!";

}
else
echo "Введите <b>все</b> поля";

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="ru" dir="ltr">
<p>
<head>
<style>
body{
background-color: #A6CAF0 ;
color: #330033 ;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 2%;
}
</style>
<title><?php echo $config['title'];?></title>
<meta http-equiv = "content-type" content = "text/html; charset = <?php echo $config['coder'] ; ?>" />
</head>

<body "alink = '#0000ff' link = '#0000ff' vlink = '#0000ff' ">
<p style ="text-align: center;">

<form action="index.php?page=register" method="post" name="form">
<p>*Логин: <br><input name="name" type="text" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>*Пароль:<br><input name="password" type="password" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>*Пароль:<br><input name="repeatpassword" type="password" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>e-Mail:<br><input name="email" type="text" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>Стартовый покемон:</p>
<p><br><input name='name_poke' type='radio' value='1' class='checkbox' onChange="fcheck('rules')" ><b>001 Bulbasaur</b> - Травяной Ядовитый<br><img src=img/001.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1></p>

<p><br><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Зарегистрироваться"></p><br>
<br><a href="index.php"><<назад</a>

</body>
</html>
```

как занести Этого покемона в базу данных? Но при этом их их в регистрации будет 6

Comment: Во первых сразу несколько замечаний...<br>
Во первых лучше юзать `sha1` а не `md5`, во вторых входные данные надо проверять регулярками, то что сейчас пахнет XSS'ом...<br>
Оформите по нормальному ваш код, а то сейчас и читать не хочется...<br>
И убирите наверное css, разве он както влияет на решение Вашей проблемы?

Comment: А ещё лучше выбростье этот код в помойку и напишите нормальный.

Comment: to:AlexWindHop a почему лучше sha1 чем md5 ? (сории за спам, просто интересно..)

Comment: О-да интересные у вас ответы!

Comment: Лапшекод ужасен... надеюсь, это учебный пример, а не реальный код какого-то сайта.

Comment: @cy6erGn0m не мне тебе советовать(12 vs 5)... но подобные рекомендации к сокращению говнокода не приводят. Почти никогда. Единственный случай - это когда невыспавшийся, закрутившийся, замотавшийся профи постит рано утром код перед уходом на работу, а потом об этом забывает. Тогда когда он отдохнет, он взглянет на коммент, на свой код, последует совету и... о чудо!!! напишет все хорошо. Это не тот случай.

Comment: Ребята давайте вернемся к вопросу =)

Comment: какой вопрос, такие и ответы.. Постарался бы хоть задать вопрос нормально.. Ты реально думаешь что кому-то нефиг делать кроме как разбираться в этом гг что ты выложил ? ))

Comment: По поводу sha1 И md5 - почитай о том как подбираются пароли по хешу и какая скорость перебора md5 и sha1... Кстати - еще бы сольку добавить не помешало бы...

Comment: скорость прямого перебора одинаковая. Разве что у sha1 побыстрее, так как сама функция менее жручая. А подборы по радужным таблицам - да, тут md5 проигрывает значительно... ровно до того момента, как анмин начинает использовать многократную соль. Там уже опять пофиг кто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prikol, есть БД. В ней, в простейшем случае, должно быть две таблицы. (Рассматриваю упрощенный вариант, лишних полей сам добавишь.)

```
USERS:
id //уникальный номер в системе. Лучше auto_increment Можно использовать Username в качестве идентификатора, если он у всех гарантированно разный и не планируется менять.
username // отображаемое имя. Оно же - логин.
password // хэш пароля. Можно даже md5, но с солью. Как - поищи, я неоднократно объяснял на этом форуме. SHA1 предпочтительнее, впрочем.

POKEMONS:
id // уникальный номер зверька
user_id // идентификатор хозяина
name // имя зверька. Может быть неуникальным. Котов с именем Вася много.
hp // жизни
attack // атака
```

Что делаем дальше:
при регистрации заносим данные в ДВЕ таблицы. Как заносить данные - я тоже объяснял.
Две таблицы в данном виде - это **третья нормальная форма БД**. Чтобы у каждого человека могло быть несколько покемонов, при этом, чтобы не создавать дублирующих записей в бд.

Сначала заносим юзера. Чтобы ничто нам не помешало, блокируем таблицу от записи:

```
LOCK TABLE `users` WRITE
```

Записываем юзера(вкратце - так. Подробнее - ищите)

```
insert into `users`(`username`,`password`) values('Grozny','$super_hashed_password');
```

далее ищем его айдишник:

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Последнее: разблокируем таблицу и заносим покемона:

```
unlock tables

insert into `pokemons`(`name`,`user_id`) values ('Vasya','$id');
```